# Pivot table data

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have following data

```
  NAME | RIGHTS |
Steven | add |
Steven | update |
Steven | delete |
Mark   | update |
Mark   | delete |
Joseph | don’t have Rights |
Spike  | add |
Spike  | update |
Spike  | delete |
```

And this data, I want to manipulate as

```
  NAMEs | don’t have Rights | add| update | delete |

 Steven | 0 |1|1|1|

 Mark   |0|0|1|1|

 Joseph |1|0|0|0|

 Spike  |0|1|1|1|
```

Note that I have no idea of types of rights, it can be above 100

Comment: Is this any specific database? SQL Server? MySQL? etc?

Comment: Saurabh, Name & Rights are two different column?

Comment: yes, Name & Rights are two different

Comment: Something is not clear to me. You say that you "have no idea of types or fights" - does that mean that you want this query to be dynamic without hardcoding the rights (add, update, etc)? If you don't want to hardcode this then how will you know what the 0|1|1|1 means - you will never know which number corresponds to which right. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Jakub Rusilko, 1 and 0 is not ids. 1 represent exist and 0 for not exist. you are right my question is not that clear, by the way i have found answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + Rights +']'
                    from MyTableName 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT Name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT Name, Rights,1 as xCount FROM MyTableName
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(xCount)
                for Rights in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**Using pivot to get that result :**

CREATE TABLE #details(Id INT,NAME VARCHAR(100), RIGHTS VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #details( Id ,NAME , RIGHTS )
SELECT 1,'Steven','add' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Steven','update' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Steven','delete' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Mark','update' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Mark','delete' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Joseph','don’t have Rights' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Spike','add' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Spike','update' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Spike','delete' 

SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT  NAME , RIGHTS ,Id
  FROM #details
)A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Id) FOR RIGHTS IN ([don’t have Rights],[add],[update],[delete])
)pvt

**For Dynamic pivot use below query :** 

DECLARE @DynamicCol VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@DynamicPvt VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @DynamicCol = 
(
  SELECT STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + '[' + RTRIM(RIGHTS) + ']' FROM      
  #details FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
)

SET @DynamicPvt = 'SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT  NAME , RIGHTS ,Id
 FROM #details
)A
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Id) FOR RIGHTS IN ('+@DynamicCol+')
)pvt'

EXEC (@DynamicPvt)
```

Comment: Mansoor , thanks your answer is right but as i told i don't know exact numbers of rights, this problem i have solved in my answer.

Comment: use dynamic pivot in rights for get 'n' number of rights

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
            select NAME,
            case when [don’t have Rights] is not null then 1 else 0 end as [don’t have Rights] ,
            case when [add] is not null then 1 else 0 end as [add]  ,
            case when [update] is not null then 1 else 0 end as [update]  ,
            case when [delete] is not null then 1 else 0 end as [delete] 
             from  
            (
            select * 
            from #YourTAble 
            pivot 
            (
            max(RIGHTS) for  RIGHTS in ([don’t have Rights],[delete],[update],[add])
            )a
            )b
```

> Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Str varchar(max)
, @FinalStr varchar(max)
Set @Str=''
Select @Str = @Str + ',[' + Rights+']'
FROM (Select Distinct Rights FROM F2) A 
Set  @Str= Substring(@str,2,LEN(@Str))

SET @FinalStr =
'Select Name, ' + @Str +
'FROM F2 
PIVOT ( Count(Rights)For Rights in ( ' + @Str + ')) As A'

Exec (@FinalStr)
```

This is will give the desire result and it's dynamic too. You can have number of rights.